# how do I create databases in phpmyadmin using SQL query/queries?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

When I run the CREATE DATABASE command in the sql window, I get an error:
#1044 - Access denied for user 'xyz'@'localhost' to database 'xyz_global'

MySQL/MariaDB version: 10.6.16-MariaDB
phpmyadmin version: 5.2.1

I have root access to the server and I ran the command:
CREATE DATABASE `xyz_global` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

I expected a database named  'xyz_global'  to be created, but instead I got the error message above.
Is there some privilege that I need to turn-on in WHM/cpanel or what am I doing wrong?